# React-router: allow undefined routes to pass to server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My stack: Django app with React/react-router/flux frontend.

I'm managing some static pages (plus 404 page, etc) server-side, and want to configure my router to pass any undefined routes through to the server.

Here's how things are set up now:

```
let routes = (
  <Route name="app" path="/" handler={ App }>
    <Route name="register" handler={ Register }/>
    <Route name="login" handler={ Login }/>
    <Route name="refer" handler={ Refer }/>
    <Route name="help" handler= { Help }/>
    <Route name="list-property" handler= { ListProperty }/>
    <DefaultRoute handler={ Home }/>
  </Route>
);

router = Router.create({ routes, location });

router.run((Handler, state) => {
  React.render(<Handler {...state} />, rootEl);
});
```

mysite.com/register will get routed through the react router to my Register page component, but I want mysite.com/thanks to hit my server (so django can manage the route). Right now I get a blank page.

I'm perusing the documentation here but can't find what I need: http://rackt.github.io/react-router/#NotFoundRoute

Maybe I'm overlooking something... thanks!

Comment: All the requests, like `thanks` (as not listed) in this case should go past react-router and hit the server where they are handled. I have no experience in Django, but in my NodeJS implementation the Express middleware receives the request as expected. I've also done it with gulp-connect in another project, but that worked also as expected. `NotFoundRoute` won't help you in this case, since it's meant to display a specific component. **Could you append your django conf / URL dispatcher for routing to the question, it could help others to help you?**

Answer (score 2):

If you want certain paths to hit the server redirect to those paths using a standard anchor redirect or similar rather than use the Router.Link to navigate.

Comment: This is what I confirmed after my comment,but forgot to answer. `<Link ... />` is for react-router and `<a href ...>` for normal server-side requests.